# Rails basics link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Super easy yet I can't figure it out. How do I do this?
(Make the username appear inside the link/button)

```
 = link_to "Collaborate with @user.name", loans_path, class: "button"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
= link_to "Collaborate with #{@user.name}", loans_path, class: "button"
```

Comment: thank you........I tried this before with single quotes and it didn't work, so I guess one has to use double quotes (").

Comment: You should find out what's the difference of double quotes and single quotes. It's really basic!!!